# Most optimal way of changing all textures on scene

Tags: c#, performance, textures, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for the best way of changing the texture of all the gameobjects on scene. I need a way that affects the performance as little as possible. One of the possibilities I've considered is to attach a script to all those objects that are texturized and then somehow call a function that affects all those objects that had this script attached. However, I'm not sure how to do so, thus if some of you knows, I'd appreciate any advice. I'd also appreciate it if you could propose more optimal ways to achieve the same result. Thanks for your time.

If you are a frequent user of Unity Answers, I've raised the same question [there](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/515013/best-way-of-changing-all-textures-on-scene.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them all the child of a single empty object (call it TextureController or something) and attach a script to that that changes the texture of all of its children?  It would be an efficient way if it's possible given your setup.  Hope it helps :)

Comment: So, my conclusion is that it really depends on the setup, right? Thanks a lot for your collaboration!